# how to loop through a dictionary and access the first value? - python

Tags: python, loops

How can I loop through the dictionary and access the first value in the dictionary? Note, I know this can be done without looping but in this case, I require looping so that is why I'm a little stuck.

For example: Suppose you have a dictionary  `d = {1: "Hello", 2: "Bye"}`. I want to loop through this dictionary and return `"Hello"`. How can I do so?

I could do:

```
for first_value in d.values():
     ... # what do I do here?
```

Comment: It makes no sense to loop if you only want one value.

Comment: wrap it in a function? `for v in d.values(): return v`

Comment: The reason I want to loop is that I want to include a condition which is only accessible when you loop through the items

Comment: How do you know that Hello is the first value? Do you know the name of the key? Because dictionaries are not (typically) ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I follow, but if you want to separate the first value from the rest, you can use the unpacking operator:

```py
data = {1: "Hello", 2: "Bye"}
fst, *rest = data.values()
print(fst)
print(rest)
```

This outputs:

```py
Hello
['Bye']
```

Answer (score -1):

Break out of the loop after the first iteration:

```
for first_value in d.values():
    break
print(first_value)
```